# How to chose Color depending on System Background Color in Swift 5?

Tags: swift, view, colors, swiftui, background

I am currently working with `SwiftUI Colors`.

**Problem:** I have a `Card Component` which has a Background Color of `systemGray6`. This works fine for most Views *(all Views with `systemBackground` Background Color)*.

However, I have some `Modal Views` which come with `tertiarySystemBackground`. This doesn't change anything in `LightMode`, but changes the Background Color in `DarkMode` to the same as `systemGray6`. As a result, the Background and the Card have the same Color and the Card is not visible anymore.

**My Solution so far:**

```swift
struct Card: View {
    var isInsideModal: Bool = false

    var body: some View {
        // Some Content
        .background(isInsideModal ? Color.systemGray6 : Color.systemGray5) // I added this in an Extension of Color
    }
}
```

**Question:** Is there any Possibility of automating this Behavior without always having to explicitly pass the desired `Background Color` to the `Card View`?

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What do you mean by *automating*?

Comment: @Asperi I mean that the CardView figures out by himself which Background Color to choose depending on the Parent‘s View Background Color. So that you do not have to provide this information as a argument. Maybe the Parents View bgColor is passed as an Environment Variable or something like this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create Color Sets in your xcassets folder. It provides you with the ability to choose different Appearances depending on whether your app is operating under dark or light mode.